# Pyspark throwing error: py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I have a method in Scala file that returns a py4j.java_collections.JavaMap in my pyspark code. I believe that i can use dictionary methods on my Java map. But, I am not able to. I am trying to use a user defined function from my pyspark code where i want to fetch the value stored in **energy**-a Java Map.

**Below is my pyspark code**:

```
energy = trcProcessor.getEnergyMap()
calculateEnergy = udf(lambda op, x: x*energy.get("ACT"), FloatType())

data = spark.read.parquet(trace_base_path).select('timestamp', 'command') \
        .filter(col("command").isin(["ACT", "PRE", "RD", "WR", "MWR"])) \
        .groupby(col("command")).agg((func.count("command")).alias('count') \ 
        .select("command", calculateEnergy(col("command"), col("count")).alias("totalEnergy(Joules)"))
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o73.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong and how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't answer my question. I had a workaround- converted the Java Map to a python dict using dict(energy) and it worked for me.